# Bind html control in UpdatePanel on runtime is not working on amazon EBS

Tags: amazon-ebs

I am facing a peculiar problem related to bind html control at runtime in Update panel. Actually I have deployed a website on amazon EBS and when I am accessing this site with our domain name https://my.example.com  and use that update panel to bind the dynamic content it is not working.

But when I am accessing the same server with IP address like https://xx.xx.xx.xx:443/ then everything is working fine. I am not able to understand why custom URL is not working and my update panel is not able to display the html control on runtime and why it is working when I am using IP address to access that site.